# Why isn't there any RET instruction in MIPS, while x86 has a RET instruction?

Tags: x86, return, mips, subroutine

Why do MIPS subroutines return by `jr` while x86 return by using `ret`?

Why isn't there any `ret` instruction in MIPS?

Alternatively, why doesn't x86 use `jr`?

Comment: This is basically asking "Why does English put adjectives in front of the noun, but French puts it after?" They are different processors designed by different people and resulted in different design choices. (MIPS doesn't have an architectural stack, so where would `ret` get the return address from?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In x86, the call instruction puts the return address in memory on the stack. In MIPS, the call instruction (`jal`) puts the return address into a register.

In x86, the ret instruction removes the return address from the stack and branches to it. The MIPS philosophy doesn't combine separate steps into a single instruction. This simplifies the instruction set considerably. Removing a value from the stack and performing a branch are separate operations, requiring separate instructions. In the particular case of call/return, it also has the advantage that in a leaf function there is no need to write the return address to memory at all.

X86 has an equivalent of the jr instruction, `jmp r/m32`, with the destination specified as a register. This instruction is not usually used for function return because then a separate instruction would be needed to pop the return address from the stack into a register (but I have written code that does exactly that, in special circumstances).

Comment: The special circumstances were a situation where I was implementing a varargs function, à la printf, but I wanted callee cleanup. (Generally callee cleanup isn't used with varargs functions, but that's what I wanted, so that's what I did.)

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Callee_clean-up)